# What queries should I use for extracting symbols from a html page using Jsoup?

Tags: java, html, css, jsoup, fileutils

I am trying to extract the emojis listed on this site http://www.i2symbol.com/emoticons/angry by usin JSoup library for java.

I have noticed in the html-source of the page that every emoji is contained in the following div id:

The code for the following symbol is

ヽ(ಠ_ಠ)ノ

```
<div id="symbol_0" data-symbols="&#x30FD;(&#x0CA0;_&#x0CA0;)&#x30CE;" contenteditable="true">&#x30FD;(&#x0CA0;_&#x0CA0;)&#x30CE;</div>
```

＼(｀0´)／

```
<div id="symbol_9" data-symbols="&#65340;&#40;&#65344;&#48;&#180;&#41;&#65295;" contenteditable="true">&#65340;&#40;&#65344;&#48;&#180;&#41;&#65295;</div>
```

(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻

```
<div id="symbol_10" data-symbols="&#40;&#9583;&#176;&#9633;&#176;&#65289;&#9583;&#65077;&#32;&#9531;&#9473;&#9531;" contenteditable="true">&#40;&#9583;&#176;&#9633;&#176;&#65289;&#9583;&#65077;&#32;&#9531;&#9473;&#9531;</div>
```

So basically, the symbols are HTML HEX codes.
I looked at the the selector syntax given here https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax
But, I am unable to craft an appropriate selector query to extract these symbols out of the html page.

And also, since there are about 27 symbols thats needs to be extracted from this page. How do I save these symbols to an external text file.

With help from **@Dave**, i WAS  able to write this code. But, this prints the whole line of code, how can i just use it extract

(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻

from

```
<div id="symbol_10" data-symbols="&#40;&#9583;&#176;&#9633;&#176;&#65289;&#9583;&#65077;&#32;&#9531;&#9473;&#9531;" contenteditable="true">&#40;&#9583;&#176;&#9633;&#176;&#65289;&#9583;&#65077;&#32;&#9531;&#9473;&#9531;</div>
```

MY Java code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class HTMLParserExample3 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Document doc;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.i2symbol.com/emoticons/angry").get();

        Elements symbols= doc.select("div[^data-symbols]");
        for(Element symbol : symbols) {
            System.out.println("\nSymbol: " + symbol);
        }



    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like they all use the HTML5 data attribute (e.g. "data-symbols"), and according to the selector docs you can use the following to filter elements by the data attribute:

*[^attr]: elements with an attribute name prefix, e.g. [^data-] finds elements with HTML5 dataset attributes*

With that in mind, give this a shot:

```
Elements symbols= doc.select("div[^data-symbols]");
```

As for writing it out to a file, if you want that file to be HTML you can try something like [this](http://seleniummaster.com/sitecontent/index.php/java-tutorial/java-html/302-write-html-file-in-java).

**Update:**

JSoup has a way to do what you want listed [here](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html).

If we apply that to your case we and add it to what we previously had then we get:

```
Elements symbols= doc.select("div[^data-symbols]");
for (Element s: symbols) {
   String symbol= s.attr("data-symbols");
   System.out.println(symbol);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much

import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class HTMLParserExample3 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

 Document doc;
 try {
  doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.i2symbol.com/emoticons/angry").get();

  Elements symbols= doc.select("div[^data-symbols]");
  for(Element symbol : symbols) {
   System.out.println("\nSymbol: " + symbol);
  }
  
  

 } catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }

  }

}

Comment: When i used the code, i get the whole line <<div id="symbol_10" data-symbols="&#40;&#9583;&#176;&#9633;&#176;&#65289;&#9583;&#65077;&#32;&#9531;&#9473;&#9531;" contenteditable="true">&#40;&#9583;&#176;&#9633;&#176;&#65289;&#9583;&#65077;&#32;&#9531;&#9473;&#9531;</div>

Can you please suggest a way so that I can just get the values i.e just the symbols

Comment: Using the first symbol you listed on the original question as an example, what exactly do you want to extract? (i.e. your expected result)

Comment: I just want the values inside data-symbols=" " i.e only **"&#x30FD;(&#x0CA0;_&#x0CA0;)&#x30CE;"**

Comment: Thanks a ton @Dave! You really saved my day, I had been searching for hours looking at various code samples trying to decipher the exact sequence.